# Adding a line break to box

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a javascript box popping up with some message in it but I have not found how to add line breaks from code behind and I am asked to make it to do so, here is how it currently works:

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "key", 
"function SendBox() {location.href = 'movetopage.aspx';}
 if(confirm('Move the items:" + myListOfItems + ". Do you want to continue? ') == true)
 {SendBox();};", true);
```

That shows ok on the page, but now I need to add the following line

```
"Clicking OK:  Moves the items and continues"
```

So the end bos should show like this

```
Move the items: Books, Magazines, Newspapers. Do you want to continue?

Cliking OK: Moves the items and continues.
```

Notice the break between the first line and second line?, I am not sure how to add that into the box given the code I provided for the Page.ClientScript... etc..

How can I add that break line there to the pop up box?

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "key", 
"function SendBox() {location.href = 'movetopage.aspx';}
 if(confirm('Move the items:" + myListOfItems + ". Do you want to continue? 
<BR> 
 Clicking OK: Moves the items and continues') == true)
 {SendBox();};", true);
```

I tried adding a break 
 but would not work (makes sense) but i have exhausted options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\n` insted of `<br/>` becuase it's not htmt, for your condition you should use `\\n` because in c#  `\` should be escape

Comment: Thank you Goving, I am having now issues when I add this, the page just continues doing its thing and never stops and shows the pop up, is like the js call is now getting ignored. Weird :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried '\n' that is the universal newline indicator?